# Angular 5 + URL localization

Tags: angular, localization, single-page-application

I need to improve the SEO of a SPA built in Angular 5.

I have come across different repos that provide this feature, like https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router.

Do you know if this same repo, or another one, is able to change URL path from `www.mywebsite.com/en` to `www.mywebsite.com/fi` without having to reaload the whole page?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not how SPAs works! try plugins like ng2-translate

Comment: Is ng2-translate pushing URL lang? I'm not looking for a translation service, I just need to localize the URLs.

Comment: Purpose: I need to integrate a 3rd party service that checks the URL language